# Typescript what should another error type?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I return a object with 2 props message and success at every query. I create this interface:

```
export interface IDBReturn {
  message: string;
  success: boolean;
}
```

Then I put it as return type in my function

```
export const createTenant = async ({
  name,
  city,
  street,
  zipcode,
  category,
  company,
  domain,
  code,
  packet
}: ICreateTenant): Promise<IDBReturn> => {
  try {
    await pg.none('INSERT INTO tenants (name, city, street, zipcode, category, company, domain, code, packet) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9);',
      [name, city, street, zipcode, category, company, domain, code, packet]);
    return {
      message: 'Tenant erfolgreich erstellt.',
      success: true
    };
  } catch(e) {
    if(e instanceof Error) {
      return {
        message: e.message,
        success: false
      }
    } else {
      return {
        message: e,
        success: false
      }
    }
  }
};
```

So at the last else statement in catch I got this error:

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

So what are else error types or what would be the best to fix this error ? I am new at typescript and want to know what would be a good way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your catch i will advice to you to add a default message as a string because instance of e can be object or something else

```
 if (e instanceof Error) {
      return {
        message: e.message,
        success: false
      };
    } else if (typeof e === 'string') {
      return {
        message: e,
        success: false
      };
    } else {
      // Handle other error types or provide a default message
      return {
        message: 'An unexpected error occurred.',
        success: false
      };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

"e" is unknown and not a string. You can use String(e) to convert any error to its string representation, ensuring type safety:

```
[...]
catch(e) {
  return {
    message: String(e), // Convert e to a string
    success: false
  };
}
```